# How to add more.. button to search results

Tags: php, javascript, search

I'm creating a website that shows 20 search results from the searched query, by taking the results from the database. If, in the address bar, the user has `$n=(number)` the number of results would be that number. So I thought of creating a button that resends the request but with `$n=$n+10` , but that would refresh the page and I want a way to keep the user on the page and show 10 more results quickly and easily. Any ideas?

Comment: did you hear about ajax ? look on this link http://beski.wordpress.com/2009/04/20/ajax-pagination-with-jqueryphpmysql/

Comment: nothing bad in refresh. no need to keep the user on the page! Another page of search results IS another page.

Comment: I don't have much experience with it so a little more info would really help me out.

Comment: the link i wrote, explain how to do this with a demo and all source code

Comment: @Col. Wouldn't it be annoying for the user? I, personally, don't mind when websites refresh but users can be picky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two ways. Regular way that refreshes the page and ajax. If you are new to Ajax, I suggest you to use jQuery functions. It makes everything much easier to load that extra data and display them without refreshing the page.

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

I suggest you to start with jQuery.post() function since you are new to this.